# How do i properly move multiple items in a single listView control to another listveiw control in javaFx?

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have made it possible to have multiple items in a list move to another list but when i move it to the other list [] these pop up around the just moved item and the multiple choices that are chosen are all on a single line in the list view control rather then it being individually listed items going vertically down the list.I need this for an assignment. Here is what i have.

```
package com.company.javaFxPractice;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;

import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.application.*;

public class ListProblem extends Application
{

    ObservableList<String> girlNames;
    ObservableList<String> boyNames;

    Button moveLeftButton;
    Button moveRightButton;

    Scene scene1;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("List Problem");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        scene1 = new Scene(gridPane,350,200);

        ListView<String> data = new ListView<String>();
        data.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        girlNames = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
          "Meagan Good", "Jessica Alba", "Erykah Badu", "Beyonce", "Janet"    
        );

        data.setItems(girlNames);

        ListView<String> data2 = new ListView<String>();
        boyNames = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
         "Eddie Murphy", "Richord Pryor", "Eddie Griffin", "Kevin Heart", "Mike"
        );

        data2.setItems(boyNames);
        gridPane.setConstraints(data, 0, 0);
        gridPane.setConstraints(data2, 1, 0);

        moveLeftButton = new Button("Move Left");
        moveLeftButton.setPrefSize(200, 30);
        moveLeftButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        moveLeftButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            String selection = "";
      //turns selected item on left list control to a string

  selection = String.valueOf(data.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());  

       //adds selected Item to the list on the right

          boyNames.add(selection);

       // removes whatever was selected from the left list 

            girlNames.remove(data.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        });

        gridPane.setConstraints(moveLeftButton, 0, 1);
        moveRightButton = new Button("Move Right");
        moveRightButton.setPrefSize(200, 30);
        moveRightButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        moveRightButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            String selection = "";

            //turns selected item on the right list control to a string

                      selection =  
        String.valueOf(data2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());

           //adds the string to the list on the left

            girlNames.add(selection);

           // removes whatever was just selected from right list

            boyNames.remove(data2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        });

        gridPane.setConstraints(moveRightButton,1,1);
        gridPane.getChildren().
        addAll(data,data2,moveLeftButton,moveRightButton);


        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert the `selected items` into a `String`. You can (and should) directly add them to the other List.

Try using:

```
moveLeftButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        boyNames.addAll(data.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
        girlNames.removeAll(data.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
});
```

Please take a note that I am using `getSelectedItems()`, because this `ListView` has **MULTIPLE** selection enabled.

and similarly,

```
moveRightButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        girlNames.addAll(data2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        boyNames.remove(data2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
});
```

**Complete Working Example**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListProblem extends Application {

    ObservableList<String> girlNames;
    ObservableList<String> boyNames;

    Button moveLeftButton;
    Button moveRightButton;

    Scene scene1;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("List Problem");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        scene1 = new Scene(gridPane, 350, 200);

        ListView<String> data = new ListView<String>();
        data.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        girlNames = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Meagan Good",
                "Jessica Alba", "Erykah Badu", "Beyonce", "Janet");

        data.setItems(girlNames);

        ListView<String> data2 = new ListView<String>();
        boyNames = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Eddie Murphy",
                "Richord Pryor", "Eddie Griffin", "Kevin Heart", "Mike");

        data2.setItems(boyNames);
        GridPane.setConstraints(data, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(data2, 1, 0);

        moveLeftButton = new Button("Move Left");
        moveLeftButton.setPrefSize(200, 30);
        moveLeftButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        moveLeftButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            boyNames.addAll(data.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
            girlNames.removeAll(data.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
        });

        GridPane.setConstraints(moveLeftButton, 0, 1);
        moveRightButton = new Button("Move Right");
        moveRightButton.setPrefSize(200, 30);
        moveRightButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        moveRightButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            girlNames.addAll(data2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            boyNames.remove(data2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        });

        GridPane.setConstraints(moveRightButton, 1, 1);
        gridPane.getChildren().addAll(data, data2, moveLeftButton,
                moveRightButton);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```